# How to force git merge to raise always conflicts

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I created a branch `test` from the `master` branch. Afterwords, I made important changes in both branches, and I would like to merge them.

However, if I run `git merge test` on the `master` branch, I have the following problem: some files have been changed only on **one** branch, and `git` chooses the version of the file that has been modified for the resulting merge. In this case, `git` does **not** raise a **conflict**.

How can I force `git` to always raise a conflict, not only when a file has been modified on both branches?

Basically, I would like to see the following syntax for each modified file in any of the two branches:

```
<<<<<<<
... 
=======
...
>>>>>>>
```

Comment: What you're describing as desired behavior is simply not how git works

Comment: I agree, I should not have reached such a situation because I was not so confident with git. However, now I would like to run something similar to what I described.

Comment: `git diff` (`git diff branch1 branch2`) is _probably_ the command you want - i.e. to show the difference between two branches. conflicts are not the normal way to observe the difference between two references